# to extract whole of the information from xml documents

Tags: python, xml, linux, ubuntu-10.04

say i have an xml document books.xml which is:

```
<bookstore>
    <book category="web">
        <author>XYZ</author>
        <title>abc</title>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

in a file i want to store :
bookstore

book category

web

author

xyz

abc

title

how can i extract this information in general for any xml document?

Comment: What have you tried from your studies? What input do you have, and what output do you need etc...?

Comment: please anyone help me at this and raise my rank .

Comment: Do you really have an unclosed <author> and a malformed close tag for title?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) search to index your files. It works very fast, has python class to run queries, can build index skiping xml tags comments etc.